# False duplicate not getting reopened, want to self-answer

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I asked a question, which was worded so that it got closed as a duplicate. Then I re-worded it to be more specific, and added my own current answer as a comment, and flagged for re-opening. Now it seems slow to re-open, seeing how re-open review queue is not overflowing.

But I'd like to add my answer somewhere (I think it is kinda nice trick even if a bit hacky/ugly). It is not an answer or even relevant as a comment to the linked false dupe.

I am tempted to just roll back my clarification edit, and ask the edited version as a new question. Would this be bad form? If it is ok, should I link the questions, or delete the first one (it has one trivial but valid   answer with no upvotes)?

Comment: Hard to give advice without the specific question. However, dupes sometimes serve a purpose. Rolling back your edit and letting the dupe run its own course + creating a new self-answered question that's different seems reasonable though. (If you feel the dupe serves no purpose you could delete it, I guess.)

Comment: You could try using a comment to ping the person who dupehammered the question and make your case that it is not a dupe in its edited form.

Comment: *"Dear close-voter, I have changed the question so that it is no longer a duplicate, please consider re-opening."* There is a reason that sounds wrong. Jeroen has already hinted at it, and so have you in your question.

Comment: @Jeroen Aren't you afraid that everyone will follow your advice instead of going through the reopening system? Either the reopening is broken and should not be used or there is the indication that something is still wrong with the question. Just posing it again and hoping it won't be closed again may be seen as creating additional effort for potential close vote reviewers, although chances are probably good, it would work, especially if the question is further improved in the meantime.

Comment: @josliber So pinging works for close voters? Ok, I'll start with that.

Comment: ...pinging did work, got the Q reopened :)

Comment: @Trilarion: there is something definitely wrong with the reopening *process*. Namely reviewer typically spend no more than a minute to ponder if a question is a duplicate or not (because they are not seriously reviewing but gaming reviewers badges). That means they may even no read the comments and not read more than the title of the question and it's alleged duplicate. You can't do much more in one minute. Another exemple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463551/what-is-the-difference-between-exit-and-return . I commented and reponpened it 3 times... and it keep reclosing at duplicate.